# How do you get a full digital clock on the Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: 14.04, screensaver, screenlets

How to get a clock like this on ubuntu's desktop?
[image: http://youtu.be/XOcvzOSv7e8?list=PLfgoUiUw04cFSutk5tA-9NPDogMccKJEZ]

Comment: are you serious? watching this long video is just annoying.

Comment: like this? http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/use-wallpaper-clocks-live-earth.html

Comment: visit http://time.is

Answer (score 1):

Install Conky, and google for Conky scripts that will display a clock exactly like that.